# Why is it important to perform defensive copy prior to the validity check during object deserialization?

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

In Effective Java 3d Edition, Chapter 12, Item 88 (page 357) under the code fragment for `readObject` method with defensive copying and validity checking from the `Period` class it's said:

> Note that the defensive copy is performed prior to the validity
>   check...

and earlier in the book it was mentioned:

> It protects the class against changes to the parameters from another
>   thread during the *window of vulnerability* between the time the
>   parameters are checked and the time they are copied.

I understand when we need to protect the `Period` instance from TOCTOU attack at the time of its ordinary instantiation via public constructor... but why is it still so important to check the fields for  validity after defencive copying (and not before) when the `Period` object is being created via `readObject` during deserialization?

The author provides the `MutablePeriod` class who steals the references to internal fields of the `Period` object, but first it reads the `Period` object and than the fields (I mean, by the time we get the fields for further mutation, the `Period` object has already been read). It can't be done in the opposite order, can it?

The Period class:

```java
// Immutable class that uses defensive copying
public final class Period implements Serializable {
   private final Date start;
   private final Date end;

   /**
   * @param start the beginning of the period
   * @param end the end of the period; must not precede start
   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if start is after end
   * @throws NullPointerException if start or end is null
   */
   public Period(Date start, Date end) {
      this.start = new Date(start.getTime());
      this.end = new Date(end.getTime());
      if (this.start.compareTo(this.end) > 0)
         throw new IllegalArgumentException(start + " after " + end);
   }

   public Date start () { return new Date(start.getTime()); }

   public Date end () { return new Date(end.getTime()); }

   public String toString() { return start + " - " + end; }

   ... // Remainder omitted
}
```

The readObject method:

```java
// readObject method with defensive copying and validity checking
private void readObject(ObjectInputStream s) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
   s.defaultReadObject();

   // Defensively copy our mutable components
   start = new Date(start.getTime());
   end = new Date(end.getTime());

   // Check that our invariants are satisfied
   if (start.compareTo(end) > 0)
      throw new InvalidObjectException(start +" after "+ end);
 }
```

The MutablePeriod class

```java
public class MutablePeriod {
   // A period instance
   public final Period period;
   // period's start field, to which we shouldn't have access
   public final Date start;
   // period's end field, to which we shouldn't have access
   public final Date end;

   public MutablePeriod() {
      try {
         ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);

         // Serialize a valid Period instance
         out.writeObject(new Period(new Date(), new Date()));

         /*
          * Append rogue "previous object refs" for internal
          * Date fields in Period. For details, see "Java
          * Object Serialization Specification," Section 6.4.
          */
         byte[] ref = { 0x71, 0, 0x7e, 0, 5 }; // Ref #5
         bos.write(ref); // The start field
         ref[4] = 4; // Ref # 4
         bos.write(ref); // The end field

         // Deserialize Period and "stolen" Date references
         ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray()));
         period = (Period) in.readObject();
         start = (Date) in.readObject();
         end = (Date) in.readObject();
      } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
         throw new AssertionError(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: As an aside… Ironically, this shows one of the many reasons to be using the modern *java.time* classes that years ago supplanted the terrible legacy date-time classes such as `Date`: The *java.time* classes such as `java.time.Period` and `java.time.LocalDate` are **immutable**. Eliminating mutation makes these objects thread-safe.